# C# HPC Schedule a job without authentication?

Tags: mpi, cluster-computing, windows-server-2012-r2, hpc, windows-server

How do you schedule a job without authentication in C# using Microsoft HPC 2012 Pack. Every time I am trying to start one, it is asking me the password for my account. I want it to be seamless instead.